# is this a good written test or is it ugly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

```
describe "Team::Membership" do
  let(:team) { Team.last }
  let(:user) { User.last }
  let(:membership) {user.apply_for(team)}

  it "can be rejected" do
    assert_difference "team.denied_applications.reload.count", +1 do
      assert_difference "team.applications.reload.count", -1 do
        assert_difference "team.members.reload.count", 0 do
          membership.reject!
        end
      end
    end
    membership.state.must_equal "denied"
  end
```

if the application is rejected, then the scope `denied_applications` increase by one, `applications` is -1 and `members`won't change at all.

```
# team.rb
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, -> { where(team_memberships: {state: :confirmed}) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :ex_members, -> { where(team_memberships: {state: :left}) }, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :applications, -> { where(state: :pending) }, class_name: "Membership"
  has_many :denied_applications, -> { where(state: :denied) }, class_name: "Membership"
```

so my question is more likely: *is this a good writte test* or would you just write

```
team.denied_applications.reload.count.must_equal(1)
team.applications.reload.count.must_equal(0)
team.members.reload.count.must_equal(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people would argue that the difference assertions should be in different tests, but IMHO, it's not a problem in that case.

What is not optimal in my mind, is that you're calling

```
let(:team) { Team.last }
let(:user) { User.last }
```

To make sure your tests are not dependent on or interfering with each other, the database should be cleaned between test runs, so if that is done, you'd write something like:

```
let(:team) { Team.create }
let(:user) { User.create }
```

or you can use something like `factory_girl` to create records more easily, for instance if you have some validation going on and don't want to type out valid data everywhere.

Comment: i do use factory_girl `Team.last`indeed is from the seeds.rb. The whole project is that big, that we need seeds for test. a user creates a team. the team creates various projects, and some users of that team can do something with the project. i feel it's just not practical to run all these things with factorygirl, because obv. the team needs approval first, the projects need approval on and on. so just to run 1 test small test, then i need to run at least 20 lines of ruby code, just to have the test-scenario

Comment: I definitely see where you're coming from. Maybe the `factory_girl` trait feature could help you with that, so that you could have some sort of `create(:team, :approved)` or so?